# How to change legend fontname in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

I would like to display a font in Times New Roman in the legend of a matplotlib plot. 
I have changed all other tick labels/axis labels/titles to Times New Roman, and have searched the documentation but I can only find how to change the font size in a legend using the `prop` 
argument in `pyplot.legend()`

---

Of course straight after posting, I found the answer. Solution for anyone else with the same issue:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl  
mpl.rc('font',family='Times New Roman')
```

Comment: add your answer as an answer so it can be accepted and taken out of the 'unanswered' questions queue.  welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 22):

This wasn't showing up in google results so I'm going to post it as an answer. The rc parameters for font can be used to set a single default font.

Solution for anyone else with the same issue:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('font',family='Times New Roman')
```

Answer (score 15):

The `.rc` solution given changes the default font for all drawing.

Here is a solution for doing this when you don't want to change all the fonts, but just the font properties of the legend of this particular graph (a legend belonging to a particular `axis` object):

```
L = ax.legend()
plt.setp(L.texts, family='Consolas')
```

This allows you to choose a different font for the legend and the axes. I found this helpful when I needed a monospace font for my legend, but not for the axes -- allowing me to create a neat legend like this:

[image]

Note how the title is a different font than the legend - this gives me an alignment of numbers that would otherwise be hard to achieve.

Comment: good except that Consolas does not seem to come with standard installation or not a font family. `'monospace'` works for me

Comment: @DimaLituiev - Consolas is a standard monospace font on a Mac. I guess you have a Windows machine? Anyway - this was intended as a guide, not a prescription...

Comment: On my mac 10.10, `open -a /Applications/Font\ Book.app` shows 9 monospace fonts, but only `Courier` `Courier New` and `monospace` work in Matplotlib 2.2.3. See also [font_manager](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.3/api/font_manager_api.html)

Answer (score 11):

I think this is the better way.

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

## your font directory 
font_path = '/Users/frhyme/Library/Fonts/BMDOHYEON_otf.otf'

## font_name 
font_name = fm.FontProperties(fname=font_path).get_name()

plt.legend(prop={'family':font_name, 'size':20})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from 2023

```py
plt.legend(
    labels,
    bbox_to_anchor=[1, 0, 0.5, 1],
    prop={'family':'monospace'}
)
```

`prop={'family':'monospace'}` - change legend font
`bbox_to_anchor=[1, 0, 0.5, 1]` - move legend to right upper conner